# Resize MatRadioButton - ripples issue

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, size

I want to resize mat-radio-button in my angular application. I defined a style globally. For the most part it works, but the anymation effect of the ripples is not resized and if cliped byt the mat-radio-container boundaries.

```
.mat-radio-container {
    height: 15px !important;
    width: 15px !important;
}
.mat-radio-outer-circle {
    height: 15px !important;
    width: 15px !important;
}
.mat-radio-inner-circle {
    height: 15px !important;
    width: 15px !important;
}
.mat-radio-button .mat-radio-ripple {
    height: 30px !important;
    width: 30px !important;
    left: calc(50% - 15px) !important;
    top: calc(50% - 15px) !important;
}

.mat-radio-ripple-element {
    height: 30px !important;
    width: 30px !important;
}
```

I want to resize the ripple anymation as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the easy methods to do this would be to just change the `mat-radio-ripple` to a circle by using `border-radius: 50%;` so it doesn't get clipped. `!important` is not required for this property since it isn't being set by Angular Material in the first place. Also, the `mat-radio-ripple-element` css does nothing here so we can omit that.

**Updated CSS**

```css
.mat-radio-container {
    height: 15px !important;
    width: 15px !important;
}

.mat-radio-outer-circle {
    height: 15px !important;
    width: 15px !important;
}

.mat-radio-inner-circle {
    height: 15px !important;
    width: 15px !important;
}

.mat-radio-button .mat-radio-ripple {
    height: 30px !important;
    width: 30px !important;
    left: calc(50% - 15px) !important;
    top: calc(50% - 15px) !important;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: That is cleaver and it works. The only isse left is that the anymation looks like it is going too fast compared to the original version.